# When I upgrade Magento from 2.1.9 to 2.2.0 and run deploy, there is a problem occurred

Tags: magento2.2.0

[image]

Any guy who knows how to resolve this ?

thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You could try omitting the jobs parameter (-j) or using a different [deployment strategy](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-static-deploy-strategies.html#static-file-quick) like standard or compact.